# Microsoft Word: When file saved as PDF an image apears

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I have a document that has an image and then some text. When I save it as a .docx file it looks like the top image, but when I save it as a .pdf that image appears and the clipart image gets longer with out that white space.

Why is that image randomly appearing? Its no where in the document.

Could I maybe edit the actual XML code of the .docx file and delete the random image?

[image: difference]

Comment: As a test, instead of saving as a pdf, try printing it to a pdf printer driver.  What are the formats of the embedded images (or are the copy/paste)?

Comment: When I print it as a pdf it doesn't show. It also doesn't show if i just print it to a printer from word.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the original image to verify what u see in the pdf is actually part of the image - which it appears to b.
then look at the image format in word to see if it has been altered, cropped, whatever.

Comment: There is no image to look at. I have no idea where it is coming from